# Get procedure/function address of another processe

Tags: delphi, function, getprocaddress

I'm writing a program that show the thread list of all opened process.

With a similiar program (Process Explorer), I can see the thread list, with some informations, like Thread ID, Priority, Start address, etc.

I'm able to retrieve all these informations too, but Process Explorer display Start address like this:

```
ModuleName!ProcedureName+$1111
```

How can I get `ProcedureName` without injecting a dll to use GetProcAddress?

Comment: You can inject some code to do it.

Comment: Yes, but, is possible get it without injecting?

Comment: You could parse the PE header and all that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`StackWalk64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680650.aspx) WinAPi function which is part of the [DbgHelp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679291.aspx), if you want a delphi sample of how use this function try the [asmprofiler](http://code.google.com/p/asmprofiler/) project.

Comment: Yep, and look at the map2dbg utility (google for it) to translate the delphi generated map file (if you enable that in the project options) into a dbg file that is needed by Process Explorer or the Windows API. Of course, with a little Jedi help, you could also parse the map file yourself, but personally I wouldn't go to that trouble.

Comment: Thanks RRUZ and Marjan Venema!